# how can I track an online games result

Tags: security, game-engine

We need to track result of every match played in an online game.

We found 2 possible ways,

1. TCP snifing: The game usually connects to their server (we dont have access to this). When game is over it sends information to the server.
2. Reading Log: The game also creates a log file as it runs. When a user looses or wins this information is found on the log file

I want to extract this information. I can extract it well. Problem is if any gamer wants to cheat he can just put wrong information in the log file or create dummy packets.

So how can I get authenticated game information here?

For example there is a tracker from Voobly for "Age of Empires II". When a single match is completed the tracker gathers all the information. how do they do it?

Answer (score 0):

Is your tracker working solely on the client machines? I assume so, since you said you do not have access to the server.

There is no reliable way of tracking results on the client. Because, as you stated, the gamers can cheat or modify your tracker. Just gather the results and try to **filter out** the cheaters or bad results. This way, you might not have an exact score for every unique player, but you might be able to extract some useful overall statistics.